# Display logic based on field's value length

Tags: openbravo

Is it posible to create a display logic condition with the size or length of a field's value?

For example: @upc.length@<13 or anything like that?

I have tried it that way but it is not working. I would appreciate if anyone knows the logical operators for this. In the openbravo howtos is not very explanative.

Thanks.

Comment: use auxilary input? (use query to find out the length, and return boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, use an auxiliary input.

### Auxiliary Input

Name : upcLength

SQL

```
select (case when length (upc) > 13 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as length 
from  table where table_id = @table_id@
```

In Windows, Tabs and Fields, for a field add the display logic.

```
@upcLength@='Y'
```

PS: Assumed DB Postgres.